# Force player to GetKeyUp before a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am working on this 2D runner and I am using the transform.position function, but I have noticed that this makes gravity in Unity not work. I still want it to work so I have set up this artificial gravity (see in script) however if you hold the W button down the person can keep flying forever. I only want the person to be able to be in the air for a second. How do I do this?

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position.y < 0.1)
{
    target_position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + jump_force);
}

//gravity
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
{
    target_position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - jump_force);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

```
 if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position.x > max_left && transform.position.x < max_right && transform.position.y < 0.1)
    {
        target_position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + jump_force);
        Invoke("normal_position", jump_timer);

    }

}

public void normal_position()
{
    target_position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 0);
}
```

The jump timer is jut how long you want it to take until the object returns to the ground.

Answer (score -1):

You're not actually implementing any gravity, because you're waiting for a `KeyUp` event. Don't wait. Just do.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
    // Do your movement stuff
}

// Just implement gravity here
transform.position = transform.position - Vector3.Down;
```

Comment: I would not mind an explanation why this is not a valid solution.

Comment: I did not get it to work, I do not know why. I am a beginner coder and do not quite understand code yet. I am sure it would work if I knew how to execute it properly.

Comment: I really meant the person who downvoted and did not provide explanation. It does not matter that you created your own solution; only that you picked one matters.